# Replace variables from the mathematical equation with array values using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an equation like the following format

$(5)+$(6) where 5 & 6 are input ids.

each input id has at least 100 values as array.
The format is as follows

```
var data = [{id : 5, inputs :[{Value:10},{Value:10},{Value:11},...,{Value:12}]},{id : 6, inputs :[{Value:10},{Value:10},{Value:11},...,{Value:12}]}];
```

What I want to do is replace the equation variables with corresponding values from the data.

Following is my current code

```
//tpl is $(5)+$(6);
$scope.value_replacer = function (tpl, data) {
    var re = /\$\(([^\)]+)?\)/g, match;
    var valueArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        while (match = re.exec(tpl)) {
            if (match[1] == data[i].id) {
                for (var j = 0; j < data[i].inputs.length; j++) {
                    tpl = tpl.replace(match[0], data[i].inputs[j].Value);
                    if (i == data.length - 1) {
                        valueArray.push(tpl);
                    }
                }
                re.lastIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return valueArray;
}
```

If I have 100 data values , resulting array should contain 100 values. But I am getting same values. Please help me to get correct values?

**UPDATE**

My equation is user defined ie equation may be some time $(5) - $(6) or $(5)*$(6) like that.. I just want to replace 5 and 6 (ie ids)

Comment: Why don't you just loop through the input format and add all the values corresponding to each id?

Comment: I didn't get the logic.

Comment: What exactly do you want from the equation? The sum of all values corresponding to each id?

Comment: yes. That is I want.

Comment: Do you have var data = [{id : 5, inputs :[{Value:10},{Value:10},{Value:11},...,{Value:12}]},{id : 6, inputs :[{Value:10},{Value:10},{Value:11},...,{Value:12}]}]; in your controller?

Comment: yes.. sorry for the late replay

Comment: I have posted an answer. check if this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use two for loops to achieve this

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
        id: 5,
        inputs: [{
            Value: 10
        }, {
            Value: 10
        }, {
            Value: 11
        }, {
            Value: 12
        }]
    }, {
        id: 6,
        inputs: [{
            Value: 10
        }, {
            Value: 10
        }, {
            Value: 8
        }, {
            Value: 12
        }]
    }];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        sum = 0
        for (var j = 0; j < $scope.data[i].inputs.length; j++) {
            sum += $scope.data[i].inputs[j].Value;
        }
        $scope.data[i].sum = sum;
    }
    $scope.findInd=function(id){
     var index = $scope.data.findIndex(x=>x.id === id);
     return index;
    }
    $scope.multiply=function(){
     var res = 1;
     for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var idSum=$scope.findInd(arguments[i]);
        res *= parseInt($scope.data[idSum].sum);
     }
     return res;
    }
    $scope.divide=function(){
     var res =$scope.data[$scope.findInd(arguments[0])].sum;
     for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var idSum=$scope.findInd(arguments[i]);
        res /= parseInt($scope.data[idSum].sum);
     }
     return res; 
    }
    $scope.add=function(){
     var res = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var idSum=$scope.findInd(arguments[i]);
        res += parseInt($scope.data[idSum].sum);
     }
     return res;
    }
    $scope.subtract=function(){
     var res = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var idSum=$scope.findInd(arguments[i]);
        res = parseInt($scope.data[idSum].sum)-res;
     }
     return res;
    }
    console.log($scope.add(5,6));
    console.log($scope.subtract(5,6));
    console.log($scope.multiply(5,6));
    console.log($scope.divide(5,6));
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is based on $(5)+$(6). For this it is ok. But my equation is user defined. ie the equation format may vary according to user. So what I want is just replace the Id value with each values from the array. For example if I have an equation $(5) / $(6) or $(5) * $(6) replace 5 and 6 with array value. ie like 10+10 or 10 * 10

Comment: @SHADOWS I have updated my answer with all the operations. You can modify the above functionalities according to your requirements. The only thing for you to do is fetch the ids from the equations. :)

Comment: Is it working to your requirements? Please upvote answer if it helped you :)